# AWS Error: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, gradle, build.gradle

I am building an android application and have run into some trouble with my grade build.

When I build the 'app' as a whole, the build completes (with errors), but the project compiles, however this is not my issue.

I have just written a small tester class for a matching engine class I have written, and was anticipating viewing the console output to see where matches are taking place. However when i try and run the MatchEngineTester class, it does not compile, and I get the following error:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidentityprovider/AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.class
```

This error does not occur when I run any other activity or class in the project, only the matchEnginerTester class, which can be found below:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import joe_perkins.coursematch.Objects.Course;
    import joe_perkins.coursematch.Objects.User;

    /** MatchEngineTester is a test class primarily designed to test the accuracy
     * and efficiency of the simple match algorithm that determines suitable courses
     * based on keywords
     * Created by Joe on 09/07/2016.
     */
    public class MatchEngineTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        /**
         * ****************************************************************
         * Manually Create a new user, assign it some values to each member
         * variable.
         * ****************************************************************
         */

        // Instantiate new user
        User user = new User();

        // Instantiate new list to hold the user interests
        List<String> interestList = new ArrayList<String>();
        interestList.add("Pokemon");
        interestList.add("Technology");
        interestList.add("Hockey");
        interestList.add("Programming");
        interestList.add("Music");
        interestList.add("Gaming");
        interestList.add("Badminton");
        interestList.add("Tennis");
        interestList.add("Computing");
        interestList.add("Coding");
        interestList.add("Calligraphy");
        interestList.add("Reading");
        interestList.add("Writing");
        interestList.add("Travel");
        interestList.add("Foreign Language");
        interestList.add("Politics");

        // Instantiate new list to hold the user favourite subjects
        List<String> faveSubjectsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        faveSubjectsList.add("Maths");
        faveSubjectsList.add("Law");
        faveSubjectsList.add("IT");
        faveSubjectsList.add("Psychology");

        // Instantiate new list to hold the users GCSEs
        List<String> gcseList = new ArrayList<String>();
        gcseList.add("Maths");
        gcseList.add("English Literature");
        gcseList.add("English Language");
        gcseList.add("Psychology");
        gcseList.add("Biology");
        gcseList.add("Physics");
        gcseList.add("French");
        gcseList.add("Spanish");
        gcseList.add("RE");
        gcseList.add("PE");
        gcseList.add("Woodwork");

        // Instantiate a new list to hold the users A-Levels
        List<String> aLevelsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        aLevelsList.add("Psychology");
        aLevelsList.add("Maths");
        aLevelsList.add("Law");
        aLevelsList.add("Politics");
        aLevelsList.add("Product Design");

        // Instantiate a new list to hold the users interested future job titles
        List<String> futureJobTitleList = new ArrayList<String>();
        futureJobTitleList.add("Software Engineer");
        futureJobTitleList.add("Psychologist");
        futureJobTitleList.add("Game Designer");
        futureJobTitleList.add("Product Designer");



        // Set user characteristics
        user.setFirst_name("Joe");
        user.setLast_name("Perkins");
        user.setUsername("freshwaterjoe");

        user.setInterests(interestList);
        user.setFavourite_subjects(faveSubjectsList);
        user.setGcses(gcseList);
        user.setA_levels(aLevelsList);
        user.setInterested_job_titles(futureJobTitleList);



        /**
         * *********************************************************************
         * Manually compile a small list of courses, feeding them the appropriate
         * member variables in order for the course object to be whole. Courses
         * may be created using an empty constructor, however in order for matches
         * to take place, courses MUST possess keywords.
         * *********************************************************************
         */

        Course compSci = new Course();
        Course productDesign = new Course();
        Course frenchLanguage = new Course();
        Course physics = new Course();

        // List to hold course keywords for compSci
        List<String> compSciKeywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        compSciKeywords.add("IT");
        compSciKeywords.add("Computing");
        compSciKeywords.add("Coding");
        compSciKeywords.add("Programming");
        compSciKeywords.add("Game Design");
        compSciKeywords.add("Maths");
        compSciKeywords.add("Technology");
        compSciKeywords.add("Software");
        compSciKeywords.add("Developer");
        compSciKeywords.add("Software Engineer");
        compSciKeywords.add("Computer Science");


        // List to hold course keywords for productDesign
        List<String> productDesignKeywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        productDesignKeywords.add("Woodwork");
        productDesignKeywords.add("Product Design");
        productDesignKeywords.add("Graphic Design");
        productDesignKeywords.add("Textiles");
        productDesignKeywords.add("Design");
        productDesignKeywords.add("Enterprise");
        productDesignKeywords.add("Concept Product");


        // List to hold course keywords for frenchLanguage
        List<String> frenchLanguageKeywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        frenchLanguageKeywords.add("Modern Foreign Languages");
        frenchLanguageKeywords.add("MFL");
        frenchLanguageKeywords.add("French");
        frenchLanguageKeywords.add("France");
        frenchLanguageKeywords.add("French Language");
        frenchLanguageKeywords.add("Study Abroad");
        frenchLanguageKeywords.add("French Culture");


        // List to hold course keywords for physics
        List<String> physicsKeywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        physicsKeywords.add("Physics");
        physicsKeywords.add("Maths");
        physicsKeywords.add("Science");
        physicsKeywords.add("Space");
        physicsKeywords.add("Matter");
        physicsKeywords.add("Energy");
        physicsKeywords.add("Force");



        // Add keywords to each course
        compSci.setCourseKeyWords(compSciKeywords);
        productDesign.setCourseKeyWords(productDesignKeywords);
        frenchLanguage.setCourseKeyWords(frenchLanguageKeywords);
        physics.setCourseKeyWords(physicsKeywords);




        /**
         * *********************************************************************
         * Manually Create a new MatchEngine object, build the engines map,
         * assess the course suitability for given courses, and return courses
         * that are considered 'Matchable'.
         * *********************************************************************
         */

        // Instantiate new match engine
        MatchEngine me = new MatchEngine(user);

        me.buildMap(interestList, 2);
        me.buildMap(faveSubjectsList, 4);
        me.buildMap(gcseList, 2);
        me.buildMap(aLevelsList, 5);
        me.buildMap(futureJobTitleList, 5);


        me.assessCourseSuitability(compSci);
        me.assessCourseSuitability(productDesign);
        me.assessCourseSuitability(frenchLanguage);
        me.assessCourseSuitability(physics);


        me.generateSuggestedCourses(3);



    }
}
```

My build.gradle can be found below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "joe_perkins.coursematch"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.kikoso:SwipeableCards:1.1-RELEASE@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'


compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.+'

}
```

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated, I am have a strong(ish) java background, however am reasonably new to android development, and particularly gradle!

I also have noticed that their are other questions on stack overflow very similar to this one, however having tried the solutions posted to those questions (primarily clean/build) I am still at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says there are duplicate copies of AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient. It's possible that you have multiple Cognito IdentityProvider libraries included in the project, possibly one under the libs folder and the other from Maven. Would you please go check the libraries under the libs folder? Also doing a gradle clean may help.